# Printing to stdout or file without repeating code

Tags: python

I'm writing a function in Python with the following signature

```
def print_results(input_file, output=None)
```

The parameter `input_file` is just a text file, as is `output`. If an output file is provided, I want to write the results there. Otherwise, I want to print them to the standard output.

I'd like to do this in such a way where I do not have to repeat code. As of now, the function looks something like this:

```
def print_results(input_file, output=None):
    // Do some computation
    if output:
        with open(output) as out:
            // Print results to output file
    else:
        // Print results to standard output
```

Is there any way to merge the parts where I'm printing the results so that it only needs to be done once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't go easy with current code because scope of `out` is limited to `with`-block. So make your function accept streams, not the filenames.  Than it would be easy:

```
def print_results(input_file, outf = sys.stdout):
    # Print results to outf
```

That will also make your code universal, so it will accept StringIO objects.

To print to stdout, use your function like this:

```
print_results(...)
```

To print to file, use this:

```
with open(output) as outf:
    print_results(..., outf=outf)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use sys.stdout:

```
if not output:
  output=sys.stdout
else:
  output=open(output, 'w') 

print(data,  file=output) 


if output is not sys.stdout: 
  output.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

In python 3.x `print` is a function so you can easily reduce your `if/else` statements.

```
def print_results(input_file, output=None):
    // Do some computation
    if output:
        out = open(output,mode) #mode which ever you want to open
    print_func = out.write if output else print
    print_func(result)  //print result to std output or file
```

In python 2.x `print` is just a statement, so a bit complicated to acheive this, you have to import print function from future module. In top of your code use this:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```